# Active Directory Users login and logoff sessions history

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a script to generate the active directory domain users login and logoff session history using PowerShell. Below are the scripts which I tried. These show only last logged in session.

**Script:**

```csh
$searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([adsi]"")
$searcher.filter = "(objectclass=user)"
$users = $searcher.findall()
Foreach($user in $users)
{
  if($user.properties.item("lastLogon") -ne 0)
  {
    $a = [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($user.properties.item("lastLogon")))
    "$($user.properties.item(`"name`")) $a"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\working\lastlogonworked.ps1
>   Administrator 10/17/2013 13:11:31
>   DEMO 10/17/2013 13:10:54
>   User0 10/17/2013 07:07:07
>   User1 10/17/2013 06:29:27
>   User2 10/17/2013 08:39:05
>   User4 10/17/2013 08:41:36
>   User5 10/17/2013 09:38:07
>   CPU054 10/17/2013 13:11:53

Please someone help me to get the all users login and logout history.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to get that from AD.  You'll need to search the security event logs on your DCs for the logon/logoff events.

Comment: Assuming the DCs log this at all, as OFF has traditionally been the default for error level 0 events as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this thread via google looking for how logging user logons is done, and I found an interesting, and possibly simpler, method. I am by no means an AD expert and this was already put in place by my predecessor. I was trying to figure out how it was done.

- Set up a group policy to run a script at logon. In this case a script called "Logon.cmd"
- Create a small batch file and place it (in my case) here:

  C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain\Policies{81D... [SNIP} ...C7}\User\Scripts\Logon
- The contents of that script is one line:

  echo Logon,%COMPUTERNAME%,%USERNAME%,%DATE%,%TIME% >> \SERVER\SHARE\%USERNAME%.csv

Now this gives you a share filled with files, one per user, rather than logging the events directly to the Windows security log on the DC. Which could be problematic (or annoying) or it could give non-computer literate (HR and management?) folks easy access to personnel tracking information.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that users could mess with it. Otherwise, it's not a bad concept

Answer (score 1):

```
$searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([adsi]"")
$searcher.filter = "(objectclass=user)"
$users = $searcher.findall()
Out-File C:\logonfile.txt
Foreach($user in $users)
{
  if($user.properties.item("lastLogon") -ne 0)
  {
    $a = [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($user.properties.item("lastLogon")))
    "$($user.properties.item(`"name`")),$a" >> c:\logonfile.CSV

  }
}
```